# private MyDbContext _appContext => (MyDBContext)_context;?

Tags: c#, lambda, dbcontext

Please can some explain what does this code means ?

```
private MyDbContext _appContext => (MyDBContext)_context;
```

Thanks alot

Comment: you declare a private property `_appContext` which returns `_context as MyDBContext`

Comment: By calling `_appContext.Anything()` you actually call `((MyDBContext)_context).Anything()`

Answer (score 0):

```
private MyDbContext _appContext => (MyDBContext)_context;
```

is the shorthand version of the following property definition:

```
private MyDbContext _appContext
{
  get
  {
      return (MyDBContext)_context;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** correction: it's a property, not a method

Comment: That isn't a method, its a property.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called [expression bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-get-statements).

Quote from the Microsoft docs:

> If you choose to implement a property get accessor yourself, you can
>   use an expression body definition for single expressions that simply
>   return the property value.  ...
>
> Read-only properties that use an expression body definition can be
>   implemented without an explicit set statement. The syntax is:
>
> `PropertyName => returnValue`